# Can't create archived redo logs

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

Oracle 11.2.0.3 in Windows Server 2008 64 bits.
I try to set up archive mode in a database:

```
C:\Users\Admin>SET ORACLE_SID=BDSPROD

C:\Users\Admin>SQLPLUS /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Oct 25 12:28:59 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle. All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/oracle as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select log_mode from v$database;

LOG_MODE
NOARCHIVELOG

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_start=TRUE SCOPE=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET log_archive_dest='D:\oradata\BDSPROD\archivelogs\' SCOPE=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
ORA-01012: not logged on
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
ORA-32004: obsolete or deprecated parameter(s) specified for RDBMS instance
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 6781128704 bytes
Fixed Size 2268064 bytes
Variable Size 3539993696 bytes
Database Buffers 3221225472 bytes
Redo Buffers 17641472 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> ARCHIVE LOG START;
Statement processed.
SQL> ALTER DATABASE ARCHIVELOG;

Database altered.

SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

Database altered.

SQL> alter system switch logfile;

System altered.

SQL> select log_mode from v$database;

LOG_MODE
ARCHIVELOG
```

However, there is no archived redo logs generated in folder: D:\oradata\BDSPROD\archivelogs\
I also tried with SET log_archive_dest='D:\oradata\BDSPROD\archivelogs' (without last "\"), but same behaviour, no archived redo log is created

Comment: Anything interesting in the alert log?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this from the [Oracle Database Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams122.htm#REFRN10085) will be useful:

> > Note: For Enterprise Edition users, this parameter has been deprecated
> >     in favor of the LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n parameters. If Oracle Enterprise
> >     Edition is not installed or it is installed, but you have not
> >     specified any LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n parameters, this parameter is valid.
>
> LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST is applicable only if you are running the database in
>   ARCHIVELOG mode or are recovering a database from archived redo logs.
>   LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST is incompatible with the LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n
>   parameters, and must be defined as the null string ("") or (' ') when
>   any LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n parameter has a value other than a null string.
>   Use a text string to specify the default location and root of the disk
>   file or tape device when archiving redo log files. (Archiving to tape
>   is not supported on all operating systems.) The value cannot be a raw
>   partition.
>
> If LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST is not explicitly defined and all the
>   LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n parameters have null string values,
>   LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST is set to an operating system-specific default value
>   on instance startup.
>
> To override the destination that this parameter specifies, either
>   specify a different destination for manual archiving or use the
>   SQL*Plus statement ARCHIVE LOG START filespec for automatic archiving,
>   where filespec is the new archive destination. To permanently change
>   the destination, use the statement ALTER SYSTEM SET LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST =
>   filespec, where filespec is the new archive destination.